# Adobe Premiere Pro doesn't use GPU when I'm editing a project

Tags: cpu, gpu, nvidia-graphics-card, adobe-premiere

I'm using as a GPU the Nvidia GeForce GTX 1060 3gb. When I open a project (selected (CUDA) for the aceleration rendering) and I'm editing,a  simple Zoom effect has a red zone in timeline, and when I press play my CPU uses about 90% - 100% resources but my GPU uses 0% - 3% resources:

> [image: task manager]

How can I solve it? Is there a way to to control if Premiere Pro uses the GPU for editing?

Comment: You can Enable hardware accelerated decoding support: https://helpx.adobe.com/premiere-pro-next/get-set-up/driver-requirements/enable-hardware-accelerated-decoding-support.html The Effects which support jardware acceleration are marked with a specific symbol in the effects pane. Other effects will use software

Comment: Also, check out this thread: https://www.reddit.com/r/premiere/comments/10zbmm2/how_do_i_get_premiere_pro_to_use_more_gpu_instead/

Comment: You may be missing a codec that can use the GPU. Try to install a codec pack, for example [K-Lite Codec Pack](https://www.codecguide.com/download_kl.htm).

Answer (score 2):

Premiere Pro can make excellent use of the GPU, provided you choose the right codecs and take care of how you construct your timeline. Hardware decoding (needed for editing) and Encoding (for export) is limited to the codecs most used by professionals. Furthermore, CUDA support means that many effects and transformations are directly calculated by the GPU.

However, be aware that comprehensively, very often the main load will still be on the CPU.

Here are some steps to take, in order of importance:

1. Enable hardware decoding: **Preferences > Media**, and Select "**Enable hardware accelerated decoding (requires restart)**."
2. Make sure you are using footage with CFR and not too high compression. Check out that you're using a codec for which hardware decoding is supported, [here is a complete chart](https://www.pugetsystems.com/labs/articles/what-h-264-and-h-265-hardware-decoding-is-supported-in-premiere-pro-2120/). Don't directly edit downloaded videos, cell phone videos, zoom recordings ecc. Premiere Pro is best at handling professional-grade footage, so **you might need to re-encode some videos before editing them**.
3. Make sure your timeline has the same resolution as your (primary) footage.
4. If your playback stutters, set the preview to 1/2 or 1/4 resolution.
5. If using High quality footage, consider making [proxies](https://helpx.adobe.com/premiere-pro/using/proxy-workflow.html), which are lower-resolution files used for editing purposes
6. Video Effects which use hardware acceleration are indicated in the effects pane:
   [image]
7. When looking at GPU usage, Task Manager can be deceptive. The percentage number is not really saying anything. You need to go to the performance tab and select the GPU to see what's really going on. There, you have Decode, Encode, 3D and Copy. But you still don't know what the [CUDA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CUDA) really is doing:

[image]